# Can't passing jtree value node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i got problem with passing value of jtree's node. I converted the node value to string, and then i passed the string to another method that return string from database to display in textpane , but it's error, the output message is "java.lang.nullpointerexception"
can anyone help me ?
here is my code

```
    public class Selector implements TreeSelectionListener {

@Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Object obj = event.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
     String node = obj.toString();

     try{
     resultt = treelistener.SelectionListener(node);


     txtpane.setText(resultt);
     }
     catch (NullPointerException ne){
         System.out.print(ne);
     }
}
}
```

and this is the treelistener code

```
            public class TreeListener {

DbConnection connection;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String result = null;


public String SelectionListener(String node) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection con = connection.openConnection();
    System.out.print(node);

    String sql = "Select penjelasan from tArtikel where judul = '%" + node +"%'"  ;
    try{


        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getString(1);
                }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.print(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return result;
}




    }
```

thank you

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

have you initialize your object from class TreeListener? Please create a code like this in your valueChanged object :

```
TreeListener treelistener=new TreeListener();
```

Please tell us again what is like after you add that code.

Comment: I have added TreeListener treelistener = new TreeListener(); , but it's still error